# javascript value not picked up by php

Tags: php, javascript, database

I have a form and the value of two of those forms get their value by javascript. The value of those files should end up in a database.
The value of the textfields shouldn't be adaptable for a common user, so I used this kind of code:
`<input type="text" name="total" id="total" disabled="disabled" value="0"> EUR`

Strange enough, the value in the database is now `0`.
When I delete the `disabled="disabled`, the value which ends up in the database is correct.

How does this come and is it possible to prevent your customers to modify the content of an input field while still getting the wright value in the database?

Comment: Please reformat your question, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: you explicitly say value="0" - why is it strange that value in your database is 0?

Comment: 0 is the default value. Point is to replace the value with something from the javascript file.

Comment: It sounds like you want to show them the data and not let them edit it. Is this correct? If so, why put it in an input field? Anything sent to the client can be changed so make sure you account for that.

Comment: is there an other way you can suggest me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" readonly="readonly" value="0"> EUR
```

Use the readonly attribute instead.

Disable does exactly what it sounds like, it disables the field and the information isn't sent through the form to the server side script. So, the server side script will get null when reading that variable.

As for your second question, you shouldn't be relying on client sided validation like this (javascript). It's fine to do so, but you should also do it server side. The reason behind this, is because you can't control what occurs on the client machine 100% (the user can modify at the packet level and get around any client sided validation you implement).

Answer (score 1):

Disabled values are not passed along when the form is submitted. What you want to use is `readonly="readonly"`

Answer (score 0):

When you set the 'disabled' flag on an input field, it prevents that field from being submitted to the web server - as far as PHP is concerned, it doesn't exist.  Use `readonly="readonly"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

disable tag disables the textbox.So user can not enter the new value and its value is "o" now.
If you remove it,actual vaule will replace it.